# Are there any issues with Activerecord class in codeigniter?

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter

I'm a little hesistant against to use it because I believe there can be some issues with it, but I don't really know it before I've tried it. Or is it good enough to use it or should I do plain sql statements? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has it's advantages and disadvantages. One advantage is that all queries are automatically formatted, escaped, and optimized. This is a big plus on the security side because we all forget to do everything that can be done to protect ourselves sometimes. Active Record doesn't forget.

One disadvantage is that it sometimes is difficult to construct complex queries with it but that's easily taken care of by just running your own. All in all i would highly recommend using Active Record. We have been using it for our enterprise level application for the last 1.5+ years and it hasn't failed us yet.

Comment: No problem :)! If you have any problems check out some threads about active record on the codeigniter forums... http://codeigniter.com/forums/